# Deshabilitar análisis de código en VS Code

Tags: vscode

Cada vez que codifico en Visual Code, me aparece un subrayado ondulado en los comentarios, en los espacios y cuando no dejo un espacio entre "", de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tiene tantas opciones en las configuraciones que soy incapaz de encontrar cómo eliminar estas sugerencias, o errores o avisos.

**¿Alguien sabe cómo deshabilitarlo?**

Comment: Hola yo se como se quita pero te recomiendo que instales este plugin Error Lens, Esto te dira por que sale esa linea Amarilla o Roja Slud

Answer (score 1):

Como dicen en [esta respuesta en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56647642/3617531)  deberías:

- Abrir la paleta de comandos con `Ctrl+Shift+P`
- Buscar y entrar a 'Preferences: Open Workspace Settings' (o preferencias de tu workspace)
- Encontrar 'javascript'. en la barra izquierda y buscar -> JavaScript Standard Style`
- Pulsar 'JavaScript Standard Style'
- Desactivar 'Standard Enable'.

> También la [documentación de Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/visualstudio/ide/how-to-suppress-compiler-warnings?view=vs-2019) sobre cómo desactivar las
>   advertencias en **Visual Studio Code**. Aunque directamente no nombran
>   Javascript en ella, entiendo que al haber instalado algún módulo de
>   Javascript, debería aparecerte más o menos lo indicado anteriormente,
>   por lo que entre una cosa y otra deberías poder desactivarlos

Answer (score -1):

El subrayado ondulado de color amarillo aparece (o al menos a mí) cuando defino variables o funciones que posteriormente no uso. El de color rojo te indica los errores, lo cual te aconsejo enormemente que no desactives. Personalmente no sé como se desactiva, pero sí se que al menos en versiones más antiguas del VSCode el subrayado en amarillo no estaba. Prueba a descargar esta versión antigua. Era la 1.35.1. Espero que te sirva.